# Show that there exist infinitely many positive integers $x$ such that $2a$ divide $2bx+(a^2-b^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers. Then my question is:

Show that there exist infinitely many positive integers $x$ such that $2a$ divide $2bx+(a^2-b^2)$

Answer (score 6):

This is not true. Say $b=a-1$ then your expression is $$2bx +(a-b)(a+b) =2ax-2x+2a-1$$ so $2a$ should divide $2x+1$ which is not true since $2x+1$ is odd and $2a$ even.